# Reading a multi-GB file takes a long time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to read an uncompressed 6GB file in a simple pipeline using `Apache Beam 2.48.0`:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    file = p | "read file" >> beam.io.ReadFromTextWithFilename("gs://bucket/big_file.json")
```

This takes more than an hour and the job must be stopped because it takes too much time. It's not the transformations or loading parts that take time, but the reading part. Same result if I use `beam.io.ReadFromText`.
I also tried to use `Dataflow Prime` to no avail.

Note that the worker pool size is scaling accordingly:

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2023-09-25T14:46:42.560Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 7 based on the rate of progress in the currently running stage(s).
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2023-09-25T14:47:39.397Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 7 to 8.
```

Currently, the script is run directly via `python`:

```
python my_script.py --flag1 --flag2
```

Will there be an improvement in read performance if I deploy a `Dataflow` template of my script with the following command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME
```

Comment: Does your json file have any delimiter?

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromTextWithFilename: if the file is not splittable based on your delimiter, the read cannot be done in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantee that there will be noticeable improvements since there are still some factors to consider such as configuration and resources that  may affect the loading performance.

Basically Beam pipelines are designed to cater to more complex or customized data processing. Its performance will be determined by the data input size or complexity, the number and network bandwidth of workers utilized for the execution, and most importantly, the code efficiency.

Ideally, you can improve your pipeline's performance by splitting your data input and have it consumed by multiple workers at the same time. You might also need to review your codes, optimizing it can contribute to performance improvement.

I found relevant resources that can help you in finding a resolution:

- [Troubleshoot slow-running pipelines or lack of output](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#slow-stuck)
- Troubleshooting Slow Running Beam Pipelines with Cloud Dataflow

  - [Part 1](https://medium.com/@mehkgupta/troubleshooting-slow-running-beam-pipelines-with-cloud-dataflow-5ad230ba90d5)
  - [Part 2](https://medium.com/@mehkgupta/troubleshooting-slow-running-beam-pipelines-with-cloud-dataflow-part-2-187f3eba2b96)
- [Incredibly slow read from GCS with GCP Dataflow & Apache Beam Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740194/incredibly-slow-read-from-gcs-with-gcp-dataflow-apache-beam-python-sdk)
- [Dataflow/apache beam - how to access current filename when passing in pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404579/dataflow-apache-beam-how-to-access-current-filename-when-passing-in-pattern)
- [Apache Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/)
- [Dataflow Observability, Monitoring, and Troubleshooting: Solving 7 Data Pipeline Challenges](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Community-Blogs/Dataflow-Observability-Monitoring-and-Troubleshooting-Solving-7/ba-p/469215)